# abraham/twitteroauth reply to a perticular tweet in PHP

Tags: php, api, twitter

Hi i am totally new here and title says it all ..
i want to reply to a tweet using abraham/twitteroauth library for twitter .. update for the twitte is working fine but i am unable to do reply thing .
I am doing this ..

> $status = $connection->post('statuses/update', array("status" =>
> $dataa, "in_reply_to_status_id" =>$id));
>
> twitteroauth_row('statuses/update', $status, $connection->http_code,
> $parameters);

this code also updates the account with value in $dataa variable but do not reply to the tweet defined in $id

Please help .
Sorry for my bad english .This is my first post.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yap . there was mistake from my side while updating the post .. after reading api document .. i found that without @username sign to perticular user it won't appear in his reply section ..

Answer (score 0):

hamdoulilah the solution is so easy

you need just to add @username for who you want to replay to

```
$status_id = '480775609728385024';

$twitt_reply = '@username the replay text';


$responce = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('in_reply_to_status_id'=> $status_id , 'status' => $twitt_reply ));
```

Comment: This answer was posted almost a year ago.

Comment: where is it i can't see it

Comment: It was right above the box where you typed your answer. "yap . there was mistake from my side while updating the post .. after reading api document .. i found that without @username sign to perticular user it won't appear in his reply section "

Comment: it not clear .... i give an example to explain

Comment: Well this helped me and I agree it was not clear